# Singular values of block matrix and stacked block column matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, block-matrices, singular-values

Let $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, let 
$$
M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}A & C \\ B & D\end{bmatrix} \quad M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}A \\ B \\ C \\ D\end{bmatrix}
$$
I suspect that:
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1(M_1) \leq \sigma_1(M_2)
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_1(M_1)$ is the maximum singular value of $M_1$.

We can show that:
\begin{align}
\sigma_1(M_2)^2 = \lambda_1(M_2^TM_2) &= \lambda_1(A^TA + B^TB + C^TC + D^TD) \\
\Leftrightarrow \sigma_1(M_2) &= \sqrt{ \lambda_1(A^TA + B^TB + C^TC + D^TD) }
\end{align}

This equality for $M_1$ is false and numerical test suggest that $\sigma_1(M_1) \leq \sigma_1(M_2)$ and I haven't been able to find a counter example.

I am having trouble proving it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your motivation for suspecting this, and on what your have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. Random counterexample: we have $\|M_1\|_2=2\sqrt{3}=3.46>3.24=1+\sqrt{5}=\|M_2\|_2$ when
$$
A=B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1},\ C=D=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},
\ M_1=\pmatrix{0&1&1&1\\ 0&1&1&1\\ 0&1&1&1\\ 0&1&1&1\\},
\ M_2=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1\\ 0&1\\ 0&1\\ 1&1\\ 1&1\\ 1&1\\ 1&1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know the kind of hypothesis we could make on A, B , C and D for the inequality to be true ?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, no, except the really obvious ones (degenerate cases like $A=B=0$ or $C=D=0$, or trivial cases such as $M_1$ is unitary).